# Failure to write subsquent compressed data to an output file in C

Tags: c, file, compression

I am reading data from an input file and compressing it with bzip library function calls BZ2_bzCompress in C. I can compress the data successfully. But I cannot write all the compressed data to an output file. Only the first compressed line can be written. Am I missing something here.

```
int main()
{
    bz_stream bz;   
    FILE*   f_d;
    FILE* f_s;
    BZFILE* b;  
    int     bzerror = -10;  
    unsigned int nbytes_in;
    unsigned int nbytes_out;
    char buf[3000] = {0};
    int result = 0;
    char buf_read[500];
    char file_name[] = "/path/file_name";
    long int save_pos;

    f_d = fopen ( "myfile.bz2", "wb+" );    
    f_s = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if ((!f_d) && (!f_s)) {

        printf("Cannot open files");
        return(-1);
    }

    bz.opaque = NULL;
    bz.bzalloc = NULL;
    bz.bzfree = NULL;


    result = BZ2_bzCompressInit(&bz, 1, 2, 30); 


    while (fgets(buf_read, sizeof(buf_read), f_s) != NULL)
    {       
        bz.next_in = buf_read;
        bz.avail_in = sizeof(buf_read);
        bz.next_out = buf;
        bz.avail_out = sizeof(buf);

        printf("%s\n", buf_read);
        save_pos = ftell(f_d);
        fseek(f_d, save_pos, SEEK_SET);
        while ((result == BZ_RUN_OK) || (result == 0) || (result ==  BZ_FINISH_OK))
        {
            result = BZ2_bzCompress(&bz, (bz.avail_in) ? BZ_RUN : BZ_FINISH);                       

            printf("2 result:%d,in:%d,outhi:%d, outlo:%d \n",result, bz.total_in_lo32, bz.total_out_hi32, bz.total_out_lo32);
            fwrite(buf, 1, bz.total_out_lo32, f_d);         

        }
        if (result == BZ_STREAM_END)
        {
            result = BZ2_bzCompressEnd(&bz);                    
        }

        printf("3 result:%d, out:%d\n", result, bz.total_out_lo32);
        result = BZ2_bzCompressInit(&bz, 1, 2, 30); 
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    }   

    fclose(f_d);
    fclose(f_s);        
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please share your code, so we can help you.

Comment: Please share your code and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There might be data remaining in the compression buffer which needs writing to file before you close the file. For example, if I am doing [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) there might be a final run length to write.

Comment: Side note: `if ((!f_d) && (!f_s))` should be `if ((!f_d) || (!f_s))`. Both files must be opened.

Comment: Another aside: I can't see why `save_pos = ftell(f_d); fseek(f_d, save_pos, SEEK_SET);` is needed, it does nothing. Also there is another strange sequence, you are checking `result` after the file write was done. The first check of `while ((result...))` is the result from the `BZ2_bzCompressInit()` call, but in subsequent loops of `while ((result...))` none of the values checked are ones that are set by the ternary operator on `BZ2_bzCompress()` futher on in the loop, for the next loop... and *after* writing to the file.

Comment: You're careful to open the output file as a binary file, which is good, but it's unclear why you do not do the same for the input file.  Depending on your platform, it might not make a practical difference, but the discrepancy stands out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** there are multiple problems, but the main one that explains the problem you asked about is likely that you compress each line of the file independently, instead of the whole file as a unit.

---

1. According to the docs of `BZ2_bzCompressInit`, the `bz_stream` argument should be allocated *and initialized* before the call.  Yours is (automatically) allocated, but not (fully) initialized.  It would be clearer and easier to change to

   ```
       bz_stream bz = { 0 };
   ```

   and then skip the assignments to `bz.opaque`, `bz.alloc`, and `bz.free`.
2. You store but do not really check the return value of your `BZ2_bzCompressInit` call.  It does eventually get tested in the condition of the inner `while` loop, but you do not detect error conditions there, but instead just success and normal completion conditions.
3. Your handling of the input buffer is significantly flawed.

   - In the first place, you set the number of available input bytes incorrectly:

     ```
     bz.avail_in = sizeof(buf_read);
     ```

     Since you're using `fgets()` to read data into the buffer, under no circumstances is the full size of the buffer occupied by input data, because `fgets()` ensures that a string terminator is written into the array.  In fact, it could be worse because `fgets()` will stop at after newlines, so it may provide as few as just one input byte on a successful read.

     If you want to stick with `fgets()` then you need to use `strlen()` to determine the number of bytes available from each read, but I would suggest that you instead switch to `fread()`, which will more reliably fill the buffer, indicate with its return value how many bytes were read, and correctly handle inputs containing null bytes.
   - In the second place, ***you use `BZ2_bzCompress()` to compress each buffer of input as if it were a complete file***.  When you come to the end of the buffer, you finish a compression run and reinitialize the bz_stream.  This will definitely interfere with decompressing, and it may explain why your program (seems to) compress only the first line of its input.  You should be reading the whole content of the file (in suitably-sized chunks) and feeding all of it to `BZ2_bzCompress(... BZ_RUN)` before you finish up.  There should be one sequence of calls to `BZ2_bzCompress(... BZ_FINISH)` and finally one call to `BZ2_bzCompressEnd()` for the whole file, not per line.
4. You do not perform error detection or handling for any of your calls to standard library or bzip functions.  You do handle the expected *success-case* return values for some of these, but you need to be rpepared for errors, too.
5. There are some additional oddities

   - you have unused variables `nbytes_in`, `nbytes_out`, `bzerror`, and `b`.
   - you open the input file as a *text* file, though whether that makes any difference is platform-dependent.
   - the `ftell()` / `fseek()` pair has no overall effect other than setting `save_pos`, which is not otherwise used.
   - although it is not harmful, it also is not *useful* to `memset()` the output buffer to all-zeroes at the end of each line (or initially).
   - Given that you're *compressing* the input, it's odd (but again not harmful) that you provide six times as much output buffer as you do input buffer.

Comment: John Bollinger: Thank you for the tip of setting bz.avail_in to strlen(buf_read). This solved my problem.